# Communication between OpenGL and GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've been reading MANY OpenGL and GLSL tutorials and I still cannot understand how to work with Shaders.
I learned that gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix is deprecated and that I should calculate the matrix "on my own" - how do I do that?
Wikipedia uses a uniform variable (I have no idea what's its point) in order to achieve that calculation.

I came across other functions that should be used with Shaders, like glEnableVertexAttribArray and glVertexAttribPointer, but I didn't get how they're connected to Shaders.

Comment: This seems to be recommended around here, and I believe it covers all your points of confusion: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/

Comment: Also for handling matrices client side, I recommend [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/)

Comment: Your question isn't too specific, but in general it sounds like you're missing some basic stuff. The concept goes like this: In an OpenGL program, you can construct a GLSL program which is passed to the graphics card for you. The program consists of shader programs (vertex & fragment). Uniforms are variables which can be passed to the GLSL program (from inside the OpenGL program). This is how you share data between the two. I hope this clarifies, but really, you either need to read better sources or pay closer attention to what you read because anything I can say has already been said better.

Comment: @delnan I'm not offended my friend. English isn't my mother language and I really fail to understand the author of the tutorials sometimes.

Comment: This is tangential, but I'm going to have to disagree strongly with delnan. OpenGL is horribly confusing to learn. The naming conventions are bizarre, the error handling is extremely poor, and the tutorials and books on the subject do very little to clarify those things. Add on top of that the myriad of add-ons for OpenGL (glu, glut, GLEW, etc.) that many books and tutorials assume you have installed or have access to, and it's a nightmare. Now adding in deprecation depending on the version you're using, and it's quite understandable that you're confused. Don't give up, though! Good luck!

Comment: @user1118321 All your criticisms are true, except that some tutorials are pretty great considering how complex a subject they are dealing with. It's not easy to become proficient, that's for sure, but it's not quite that bad. OTOH I ignored everything deprecated and went straight for 3.1+ core.

Comment: @delnan, I didn't, and spent 2 months learning OpenGL 1.1.

Comment: @user1118321, do you you know a book or an online tutorial that really teaches _everything_ I have to know? Like the new vertex-drawing functions, GLSL 3.3 and so on?
If your answer is no then I'll have to read the tutorial on arcsynthesis.org.
Thanks for the cheer btw!

Comment: I would highly recommend you these 2 tutorials, which aim for the post OpenGL 3 era :) http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/index.html & http://www.opengl-tutorial.org

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer The first tutorial explains the glsl syntax poorly. It doesn't explain keywords such as "in" and it went straight to teaching uniforms before explaining the attribute functions that it used.
The second tutorial is using VAO's which are (from what I understand) not as good as VBO's.

Comment: @Pilpel The second tutorial uses VAO and VBO's, something that I'm fairly certain is the same thing what arcsynthesis teaches you.

Comment: @Pilpel - I don't know of a great tutorial. I read Apple's docs on it, since most of my programming is on the Mac and iOS. I'm also fortunate enough to work with people who are experts at it, so when I can't figure something out, I turn to them. I do a lot of Googling on specific problems I'm having and have used [these](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/) tutorials, though they have their issues too. Certainly posting here is a good idea, too!

Answer (score 2):

I am currently learning openGL myself, but it looks like I was lucky enough to find better resources. [This](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1%3a-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html) tutorial is pretty fast paced, but covers a lot of basics. I would also mention the [OpenGL Superbible 5th ed.](http://www.amzn.com/0321498828), but personally it hasn't been helping me much. As far as your problems with matrices, it is probably best you get a basic understanding of linear algebra and basic 3D math before you go learning OpenGL. For that, I recommend [this book](http://www.amzn.com/1556229119), or the Durian Software tutorial above.

As far as shaders go, I'm probably not the best source, but simple shader construction typically goes like this:

1. Load shader into memory as a character array.
2. Generate handles for your vertex shader, fragment shader, and program objects with glCreateShader()
3. Bind the source code to your shader objects with glShaderSource() and glCompileShader()
4. Link your vertex and and fragment shaders with glLinkProgram() then enable the final program with glUseProgram()
5. Load your vertex attributes (like coordinates, texture coordinates, and normals) into a buffer with glGenBuffer() (to create handles), glBindBuffer(), and glBufferData().
6. Bind your vertex attribute array buffer (again, just your collection of coordinates, normals, and other data to be processed), and use glVertexAttribPointer() to allow it to be read correctly by your shader.
7. Uniforms and attributes are just a way to make your program on the
   CPU communicate with the shader on the GPU.
8. Draw

I'm afraid that I'm too under qualified to further explain, and basic code examples of the entire process would take up far too much, but I could offer small bits if necessary. However, the resources I linked to each come with complete examples.

Comment: You led me into a trap mate. The tutorial you linked me to is using a deprecated version of GLSL. :(

Comment: Will learning it help me or will it be a waste of time?

Comment: Whoops, I forgot it uses older shader code. For those examples specifically, just replace "attribute" with "in" and "varying" with "out" on the vertex shader and "in" on the fragment shader and change the version number and it will compile fine. As for whether or not you should learn the older shader language, that is a hard question to answer. Personally, I would stick with the newer one, but knowing a couple deprecated counterparts can't hurt. After all, not everyone has the latest hardware.

Answer (score 0):

these tutorials are pretty straight forward
http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/
just follow it and do not do anything funky with matrices.

to use vertex attributes you need to define it in your GLSL shader:

```
attribute float attribute_name; //or another type

void main()
{

/// do it

}
```

and pass array in your cpp/c:

```
glUseProgram(program);
//get location of your attribute variable
GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation(program, "attribute_name"); 
//enable it
glEnableVertexAttribArray( loc );
//and pass the value
glVertexAttribPointer(loc,1,GL_FLOAT,GL_TRUE,0,attr_array);

//pass other stuff as usual
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, uvs );

glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

glVertexPointer ( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, ver );

glEnableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY );

glNormalPointer (    GL_FLOAT, 0, nor );

//do draw
```

Answer (score 0):

I found roughly the same to begin with. A lot of the online reads didn't explain in as much detail as I would have liked. Combined with the different versions of OpenGL and GLSL I had a few wtf moments.

However my most recent purchase was the [OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide (ISBN-10: 0321502795, ISBN-13: 978-0321502797)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0321502795/). It focuses on ES 2.0 which I think is a good starting point to the GLSL. I haven't actually tried any of the exercises yet as I prefer to read first and then go back through and experiment. However I'm ~100 pages in so far and everything has been brilliantly explained and in a sensible order for a new-comer.

If you combine this book with [Essential Mathematics for Games and Interactive Applications: A Programmer's Guide (ISBN-10: 0123742978, ISBN-13: 978-0123742971)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0123742978/) then that should be plenty to get going with.